# How to access a struct tag from inside a field-type in golang

Tags: go, time, reflection, tags

I want to know if and how it is possible to access a struct tag set from a custom type used inside this struct.

```golang
type Out struct {
    C Custom `format:"asd"`
}

type Custom struct {
}

func (c Custom) GetTag() string {
    // somehow get access to `format:"asd"`
}
```

My goal is to be able to define a timeformat for un/marshaling and handle the actual time-unmarshalling parameterized by the structtag.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to associate the tag with type `Custom` or is the tag associated with the use of `Custom` in `Out.C`?

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. Tags belong to struct fields, not types. So type `C` has no way of knowing what tag was used. Also, how would it work if:

```
type A struct {
  C Custom `tag1`
}
type B struct {
  C Custom `tag2`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with reflection.

```golang
type Out struct {
    C Custom `format:"asd"`
}

type Custom struct {
}

func (c Custom) GetTag() string {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(Out{})

    f, ok := t.FieldByName("C")
    if !ok {
        return ""
    }

    return f.Tag.Get("format")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the question has `reflection` tagged, to go that route you'd need to pass in the `Out`-type in some fashion to your un/marshalling methods e.g.

```
var o *Out // nil-pointer so we don't waste any space

c := Custom{}

// bs is of type []byte{}

err := MyUnmarshalerWithReflect(bs, &c, o)
```

So maybe this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and it's more intuitive to `Unmarshal` directly with the desired time-format e.g.

```
err := MyUnmarshalerWithTimeFormat(bs, &c, "2006-01-02")
```